# GET Request - how to store the data.

Tags: javascript, json, request

Currently I have a GET request on an endpoint like this -

```
orginazation(sfid: string): Observable<IBaseEngagement> {
const url = `${this.baseURL}/${ENDPOINTS.organizations}/${sfid}`;
return this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json() as IBaseEngagement);
```

I access the data from the IBaseEngagement which is an interface.

I now have a new endpoint but calling it on the same interface didnt work,
I think because it has new fields, I also tried to create a new interface it didnt work, I checked the endpoint in postman and it worked.

Am i missing something here?

Interfaces:

```
  export interface IEngagementUser extends IBaseEngagement {
  startDate?: string;
  endDate?: string;
  status?: string;
  statusLabel?: string;
  account?: IEngagementUserAccount;
  position?: IEngagementUserPosition;
  primaryPosition?: string;
  badgeType?: string;
  engagementRole?: string;
}

export interface IEngagementUserPosition {
  id: string;
  organizationId: string;
  organizationName: string;
  positionTitle: string;
  positionLevel: string;   <----- here is whats currently being used.
  isPrimary: boolean;
  startDate: string;
  endDate: string;
}
```

I want to access that same field (arrow pointed towards) that is retrieved from the new endpoint, the new endpoint has similar fields to the interface above.